# php/mysqli delete functions is accesed but it doesnt delete the item

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm making an oop delete function in php for mysqli.
The function is executed but it doesnt delete the given item.

Ths is my code:

**PHP (Mysqli class)**

```
  class mysqli_Functions
  {
        private $conn;

        function __construct()
        {

            $this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","usbw");

            if (!$this->conn) {
                echo "Cannot connect to server";
                exit();
            }

            $db = mysqli_select_db($this->conn,"geweldig");


            if (!$db) {
                echo "Cannot select database";
                exit();
            }
        }


        public function selectAll($tablename)
        {
            return mysqli_query($this->conn,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);
        }

        public function select()
        {

        }

        public function update()
        {

        }

        public function delete($query, $realEscape = false)
        {
          if(!empty($realEscape)){
            $what = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $realEscape);
            $q = $query .' '. $realEscape;
            return mysqli_query($this->conn, $q);
          }
          else{
            return mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
          }
        }
    }
```

**PHP (Where function is called)**

```
<?php
   $mysqli_Functions::delete("DELETE FROM modules WHERE id=" , $_POST['id']);
?>
```

**Ajax code(To trigger the event)**

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'actions/module-delete.php',
          data: {'id': id}
        });
        // Reload
        setTimeout(function(){
          location.reload();
        }, 2000);
  }
```

So with the code above im trying to delete items with a id. The id is in a button so thats why we use AJAX.

Can someone explain why the code above isnt deleting the items by id

Comment: Please don't make an "oop function". Use raw mysqli without any intermediate classes

Comment: Besides, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You have to use prepared statements.

Comment: Where is id assigned a value in the Ajax function?

Comment: Select * is not efficient, you should not really have a selectall function.

Answer (score 1):

`$mysqli_Functions::delete()` looks like it's calling `delete()` statically, but I'm not sure because you use `$mysqli_Functions` instead of a classname, so:

- There is no `$this` as its not an object
- The `__construct()` is never called anyway

You should try:

```
$db = new mysqli_Functions();
$db->delete("DELETE FROM modules WHERE id=" , $_POST['id']);
```

Notice `->` and not `::`.

Comment: I'm already doing that on index.php as `$mysqli_Functions = new mysqli_Functions();`

Comment: But you are calling statically with `::` don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling the method as an static? 
You should call it as a public, something like this one:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$query = "DELETE FROM modules WHERE id = {$id}";

$mysqli = new mysqli_Functions();
$mysqli->delete($query, $id);
```